# Problema al usar GeckoDriver para Selenium en python (spyder anaconda). Error: WinError 216

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import webdriver_manager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"path\geckodriver_.exe")
```

> ERROR:
> OSError: [WinError 216] Esta versión de %1 no es compatible con la versión de Windows que está
> ejecutando. Compruebe la información de sistema del equipo y después póngase en contacto con el
> anunciante de software

También he probado:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service 
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```

Pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Edité el código asumiendo que quisiste usar triples acentos graves (```) en lugar de triples comillas simples (''').

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

He tenido el mismo problema y [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74437104) lo solucionó. En mi caso tuve que usar el código para Selenium 4:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```

Comment: También a mi me sirvió tu respuesta, gracias, lo que me parece extraño es que el error empezó a suceder un día sin que moviera yo nada del código, antes solo usaba: webDriver = webdriver.Firefox() y funcionaba.